# How to change Label text color in amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have to change label text to green and red color.how can we change the color of a label using java script amcharts. and is it possible to add a up arrow after the label text.Please check the code below.

[image]

```
     var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [],
   "type": "serial",
              "theme": "light",
              "categoryField": "name",
              "rotate": true,
              "startDuration": 1,
              "startEffect":"easeOutSine",
               "columnSpacing": 0,
              "autoMargins": false,
              "marginBottom": 0,
             "pullOutRadius": 0,
              "categoryAxis": {
                  "inside": true,
                   "gridPosition": "start",
                   "gridAlpha": 0,
                   "axisAlpha": 0,
                   "tickPosition": "start",
                   "tickLength": 0,
                  "position": "left"
              },
              "trendLines": [],
              "graphs": [
                {
                  "balloonText": " [[name]]: $[[amt]]<br> Index: [[Index]]",
                  "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                  "fillColorsField": "color1",
                  "id": "AmGraph-12",
                  "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                  "title": "amt",
                  "type": "column",
                  "valueField": "value",
                  "showHandOnHover":true,
                  "labelText": "[[Index]]",
                  "labelPosition": "right",

                  "fixedColumnWidth": 15
                },
                {
                  "balloonText": " [[name]]: $[[amt1]]",
                  "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                  "fillColorsField": "color",
                  "id": "AmGraph-22",
                  "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                  "title": "amt",
                  "type": "column",
                  "valueField": "value1",
                  "showHandOnHover":true,
                  "fixedColumnWidth": 15
                }
              ],
              "guides": [],
              "valueAxes": [
                {
                  "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                  "axisAlpha": 0,
                  "gridAlpha": 0,
                  "labelsEnabled": false,
                  "minimum":0
                }
              ],
              "allLabels": [],
              "balloon": {
              "fillColor": "#000000",
               "color": "#ffffff",
               "fillAlpha": 1.0,
                "offsetX": 0,
                  "offsetY": 0,
                  "horizontalPadding":0,
                  "maxWidth":100
              },
              "titles": [],
              "export": {
                "enabled": true
              }


} );
```

Please Suggest me How can i achieve this.Also check this JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ArunKumarUmma/21wm5hf5/6/

Comment: did you mean balloon text?

Comment: No,i am displaying label right side (2.45).how can i change that color to green

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the label color using the [`color`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#color) property in the graph object:

```
  "graphs": [{
    // ...
    "color": "#008000",
    "labelText": "[[Index]]"
  },
```

[`color` demo](https://jsfiddle.net/21wm5hf5/7/)

If you need to specify it for each individual column, then you have to set the color in your data and use [`labelColorField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelColorField) to access it. If you have a `color` property set, it will fall back to that color if a particular data element does not have an associated `labelColorField` property.

```
  "dataProvider": [{
    // ...
    "labelColor": "#880000",
    "name": "Name1",
    "value": "148773.88",
    "value1": "60794.55"
  }, // ...
  ]
  "graphs": [{
   // ...
   "color": "#008000",
   "labelColorField": "labelColor",
   "labelText": "[[Index]]"
  },
```

[labelColorField demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1nye332f/1/).

**Edit again**

You can add arrows by inserting the unicode escape string. For example, the up arrow is \u02191 and down arrow is \u02193.

For example:

```
"labelText": "[[value]] \u02191",
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nye332f/2/)

If you need to do this dynamically, you'll need to set a [`labelFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelFunction) and figure out a way to determine which arrow to use. Check its documentation and figure out the best way to use it for your setup.

Comment: Please check I have updated my question.attached the image.i need label text as like that

Comment: Arrows and label color is working fine .but i need to align all the labels into a same line like image attached.is it possible ?

Comment: Not out of the box. The labels are always tied to their associated column.  Using that knowledge, you can set an invisible clustered column at a value where you want the label to be placed and set that column's labelText, color, etc,  but that's pretty much it. Here's a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1nye332f/6/

Answer (score 4):

I wish that the documentation was more clear, but you can change the label colour with nested properties so:

```
chart.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("white");
```

This would target your labels and change their colour.

Answer (score 0):

I needed my font color to be dark since my charts bg color was white:

```
xAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color('#000000');
yAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color('#000000');
```